# where are the installation logs stored while installing rhel 6.3

Tags: linux

During installation of, say rhel 6.3, the control+3 virtual console shows some text logs. I want to review these logs after / during installation (but obviously the display gets truncated). How can we do that? Is there any syslog method or the log is saved somewhere in ramdisk / file system?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your installation logs will be saved to

```
/root/install.log
/root/install.log.syslog
```

You may also find more detailed logs in:

```
/var/log/anaconda*.log
```

Comment: Didn't work. The install log contains "installing this package" something like that. That means incomplete only. Similarly the other log is also incomplete. I want the install log from the beginning including the anaconda log.

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do? I can't think of anything that might be useful for any practical purpose that wouldn't be in those logs.

Comment: omg! What are you talking about? I need to find out the errors encountered. If it is not visible because other piles of information has cleared the screen then how am I supposed to understand the error message that showed up before? Last time, it happened is that it is doing dhcp discover and it says no link to eth2 found then it goes to dhcp discover for eth0, eth1, etc. And eventually it finds the connection. I am pretty sure, that eth2 has the connection because the mac address shown during pxe handshaking matches with eth2. Hence quite obvious I need the whole of the logs - not a window.

Comment: And then it makes perfect sense to see the logs after installation because even though it says it cant dhcp discover with eth2 and keeps nagging but finally it is able to install. Hence it is needed to see the source of the trouble if it is persistently stored in the local file system after installation. After reviewing the errors I can modify my kickstart and syslinux configuration file if necessary.

Comment: You should have mentioned all of this in your original question.